# Mark OpenAPI schema enum value as deprecated

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui

Is there a possibility to mark specific enum values as deprecated in OpenAPI defintion?

For example, how can I mark Value1 as deprecated?

```
type: string
title: CustomEnum
enum:
  - Value1
  - Value2
```

Comment: no, only the property which carries the enum can be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is no if you're using OAS 3.0.x because it's limited to the use of JSON Schema draft-04 superset and subset.

If you're using OAS 3.1.x, you have the full capability to use JSON Schema and `deprecated` was introduced in JSON Schema 2019-09. Thus, you can refactor your enum with the following:

`oneOf` or `anyOf` in this situation can be equally substituted.

```yaml
oneOf/anyOf:
  - const: 'red'
  - const: 'green',
    description: green is deprecated, use red or blue
    deprecated: true
  - const: 'blue'
```

OR

```yaml
oneOf/anyOf:
  - enum:
      - red
      - blue
  - enum:
      - green
        description: this is deprecated
        deprecated: true
```

If you're using any type of code generation, either of these will probably be a breaking change because you no longer have the enum defined at the top level of this property. Now it's a union type and your code generator may have some difficulty with that.

It's important to know the `deprecated` keyword is merely an *annotation* and does not prevent successful validation. *This keyword indicates that applications should refrain from using the declared property.*

*src: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/annotations*